# Is there any way to have more than 2 inputs in ANFIS?

Tags: python, pycharm, artificial-intelligence, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm facing a problem with ANFIS model if the number of columns used in X range exceeds two I will receive an error as below. Is there any way to increase the number of Inputs ? Thanks In advance

import anfis

import membershipfunction

import mfDerivs

import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

ts = pd.read_csv("ANFIS training sets.csv")

X = ts.iloc[:,0:3].values

Y = ts.iloc[:,-1].values

**Error**:

**Number of variables does not match number of rule sets**
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/UTAR/ANFIS monthly Inflow.py", line 16, in 
anf.trainHybridJangOffLine(epochs=5)

File "D:\UTAR\anfis.py", line 66, in trainHybridJangOffLine
[layerFour, wSum, w,] = forwardHalfPass(self, self.X)

File "D:\UTAR\anfis.py", line 178, in forwardHalfPass
layerOne = ANFISObj.memClass.evaluateMF(Xs[pattern,:])

File "D:\UTAR\membershipfunction.py", line 22, in evaluateMF
return [[self.funcDictself.MFList[i][k][0] for k in range(len(self.MFList[i]))] for i in range(len(rowInput))]

File "D:\UTAR\membershipfunction.py", line 22, in 
return [[self.funcDictself.MFList[i][k][0] for k in range(len(self.MFList[i]))] for i in range(len(rowInput))]

**IndexError: list index out of range**

Answer (score 0):

Anyway after reading through python libraries it just accept 2 inputs so my advice is do use MATLAB as it is a lot more easier as ANFIS is already built in it